# Client with IP address is not allowed to access the server Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am facing the below error when I try to connect to the Azure SQL database of my free trial account. Can anyone help me how to set rules in my free trial account? I don't see any option to set them.

```
Cannot open server 'ccaausprddb001' requested by the login. Client with
IP address '125.16.236.150' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable 
access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on 
the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address 
range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. 
ClientConnectionId:f1ce6d56-c321-4458-a8dc-507f40e24108
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open server 'ccaausprddb001' requested by the login. Client with IP address '125.16.236.150' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
```

Comment: As an alternate option, I would recommend doing some research on User Assigned Managed identities.

Answer (score 51):

This can be solved by configuring the Firewall of the Azure SQL Server where the SQL database resides. I am using the new Microsoft Azure Portal. Please see the screenshot below,
[image: Selecting the SQL server from the listed resources]
Remember, you need to configure the Firewall and manage the IP addresses in SQL Server, not the SQL database.

Once you have selected the SQL Server,

- Click the *Settings -> Firewall*
- You will be requested Add a new Rule.
- Add a name and enter the IP address(or the range) that will access
  the database. note: Azure automatically detects your current IP.

[image: Follow these steps]

Wait for 5 minutes and you are ready to go. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is great but the problem is my IP address seems to keep changing and every another time I try to connect to the SQL Database from SSMS, it gives me this error: "Your client IP address does not have access to the server..." So, the question is how to find the ip address range for my computer that would resolve this.

Comment: If you're connecting from the different subnet, you need to add it under _Virtual networks_ (in _Firewalls and virtual networks_ section) of your _SQL server_.

Comment: The Azure Portal blade navigation has changed as of March-2023. This is now inside `Security > Networking > Public Access Tab`.

Answer (score 23):

You need to set up server-level firewall rules for your server in the Azure portal. 
Go to the database that you have created by clicking SQL databases in left hand menu and select set server firewall as following figure.

[image]

Under the firewall settings click add client IP and save it. It will automatically add your ID address and a server-level firewall rule is created for your current IP address.

[image]

Now you can login to your azure SQL server database using SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 20):

Using portal.azure.com (recommended), select your sql server (hosting your database) and click Show firewall settings. Select Add client IP and press save.

Using manage.windowsazure.com,
select SQL Databases from the list on the left side. Then Servers tab, from there go to the server hosting your database. Go to Configure Tab. Select Add to the allowed ip addresses arrow against your current client ip address.

Answer (score 6):

**ADD and EDIT Client IP Address in Azure SQL DB**

[image]

we will see how to Add, Edit (and Delete) Client IP Addresses in Microsoft Azure Portal step by step for Azure SQL DB.

**What is Azure Firewall?**

Azure Firewall Services are managed cloud-based network security services that protects our Azure Virtual Network resources.
It’s a supports high built-in availability and gives unrestricted cloud scalability.

[image]

**To Add and Edit Client IP Address in Azure Portal**

***STEP 1-***

If we connect SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) in Azure SQL Db at work from home or outside the access-able range, the below popup would come after entering all credentials correctly. This is for security strengthen purposes and protects our server from unauthorized accesses.

[image]

***STEP 2-***

we have to connect with our Microsoft authorized account and password needs to be entered. This step is also for protecting our servers from unauthorized accesses.

[image]

***STEP 3-***

If we are already given with Azure Firewall access, then we can Add our Client IP (Internet protocol) Address here itself. Or else, we have to follow the below other steps in Azure Portal.

[image]

***STEP 4-***

Go to Google and Type ‘portal.azure.com‘ like below.

[image]

***STEP 5-***

In the Azure Portal, type and choose SQL databases.

[image]

***STEP 6-***

In the below step, Click the DB Name(DB name is hyperlinked here in this page).

[image]

***STEP 7***

In this Page, Server,DB,Subscription,Resource related details would show up. Click the Server Name (hyperlinked) like below.

[image]

***STEP 8-***

In this Portal page, Click the Firewalls and Virtual Networks (hyperlinked)

[image]

***STEP 9-***

In this Firewalls and Virtual Networks page, We can Add,Edit and Delete Client IP Address.

[image]

Like below,

1–> We can give new name in Rule name and have to fill Start IP and End IP. If we have Single IP, then paste them in both Start and End IP Places.

2–> We can Also Edit the Existing Rule Name and Start/End IP’s.

[image]

***STEP 10-***

We can also Delete any Existing Client IP Address (3 dots at the end – Click it, Delete Option Would Come like below).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I followed similar steps commented by everyone which helped me a lot, still i was unable to connect.
I found issue was with my IP address as it was not detecting properly after setting many times in Add IP rule, provided my machine IP  by typing ipconfig in cmd prompt but no luck.

Tried using public IP via link - https://www.whatismyip.com/  it resolved the above issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server"
when you access sqlserver from azure resources like azure app service , azure funtion etc..
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution:
If IP is something like : 40.333.225.43

In my case I am using mysql.

So go to your mysqldatabase > Connection security

and set same ip in Firewall rules (StartIP and EndIP) and Save.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your azure sql server -> Security tab -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> Add Client Ip.

This will automatically add your current IP and resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

This works not for all the issues as stated:
Alternatively you need to perform as suggested below:

Run `sp_set_firewall_rule` on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.

Answer (score -1):

Error: Client with IP address is not allowed to access the server Azure SQL database

I had this issue while connecting AZURE SQL Database,

Go to Firewall settings -> Click Add Client IP.

Above will add the current IP to in the list, now you should be able to login and query.

Comment: Duplicate solution of [Swinkaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1610682/swinkaran) but without the helpful screenshot.