# Too many redirects and AzureblobTraceListener

Tags: c#, azure, redirect, trace

After re publishing my application (which has always worked just fine) I am no longer able to navigate to my site, with this error:

### This page isn’t working

#### mysite.azurewebsites.net redirected you too many times.

#### Try clearing your cookies.

### ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

And I get this unbelievably annoying error message in the log stream as soon as I navigate to the site:

> System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

What is all this about? I have no idea what `AzureBlobTraceListener` is, and I have no need for it. How can I just remove this irritant from my life?

I am not using cloud storage - my app is just simply authenticating against O365, then redirecting to the site. It works fine when debugging from VS.

---

**update**

F12 network logs (not sure how to post these as it doesnt let me copy and paste the logs, which is pretty ridiculous):

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

In my `BaseController` I have this action for handling errors

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        return;
    }

    var logger = new Logger();
    logger.LogError(filterContext.Exception, ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());

    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary()
        {
            {"exception", filterContext.Exception}
        }
    };
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

### Error.cshtml

```
@{ 
    var exception = (Exception)ViewData["exception"];
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error.</h1>
    <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

    <p>@exception.Message</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please open up Chrome Developer Tools, enable `Preserve Log`, load the page and show us the network requests.

Comment: @mjwills I added some screens of the requests, but not sure how helpful that is as it just shows a bunch of error redirects... Is there anything else I can get that might be useful?

Comment: It is weird to see a web request for `Error.cshtml`. You wouldn't expect to see `cshtml` in a web request. Is `Error.cshtml` mentioned anywhere in your code or config files?

Comment: @mjwills I updated my answer. I am redirecting to `error.cshtml` but know that this does normally display an error and seems to have worked fine in the past.

Comment: @mjwills I think the `error.cshtml` might be a bit of a red herring - I opened another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403408/an-error-occurred-when-trying-to-create-a-controller-make-sure-that-the-control)

Comment: 90% chance your error view has a bug in it. Raising an error, thus redirecting to the error view. Which raises an error, thus redirecting to the error view. etc etc

Comment: @mjwills But why does it only do that after publishing to azure? I will add the view code to the question

Comment: Wild guess: could you be out of credit on that Azure account?

Comment: @HansKesting I have actually narrowed this problem down after hours of troubleshooting, and the issue is due to my SharePoint credentials being rejected **BUT only after publishing to Azure**... You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404829/csom-authentication-succeeds-when-debugging-but-fails-on-azure-app-service) if you are interested... I would really appreciate any help