# An error occurred when trying to create a controller. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a ridiculously frustrating issue with an app that has always worked fine in terms of publishing to Azure and then running.

Suddenly, when running it today I can see this error in my logs:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MYPROJECT.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

**Note** that the application should not even be reaching `HomeController` yet, because I have not yet authenticated against MS O365... this makes no sense.

And then several errors after this:

> Path '/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml' was not found.

Which is of course a separate issue.

However, neither of these are an issue when running the app from in VS. I.e. the app does redirect to `Errors.cshtml`, and there is no problem with the `HomeController` constructor.

I already tried

1. Deleting everything from the server and republisng
2. Adding an empty constructor as the error suggests

But these don't help at all.

Home controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    GraphService graphService = new GraphService();

    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected InMemoryCache cacheService;
    protected MyEntities db;
    protected UserManager userManager;
    protected IEnumerable<SharePointUser> users;
    protected CRMTItemsManager crmtItemsManager;
    protected SPClient spClient;

    public BaseController()
    {
        spClient = new SPClient(AppSettings.SharePointBaseUrl);
        crmtItemsManager = new CRMTItemsManager();
        cacheService = new InMemoryCache();
        db = new MyEntities();

        users = cacheService.GetOrSet(Config.UsersCacheKey, ()=>UserManager.GetUsers());
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        var logger = new Logger();
        logger.LogError(filterContext.Exception, ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary()
            {
                {"exception", filterContext.Exception}
            }
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction? I have absolutely no idea where to even start troubleshooting this

Comment: Is it possible to provide complete stack trace or full exception message?

Comment: `new GraphService` is likely throwing an exception. Or something in the `BaseController` constructor.

Comment: @KaranDesai I added the stacktrace that is logged from my `OnException` action to the question. Appreciate any advice you can give

Comment: @mjwills I removed that line from `HomeController` and republished but its doing the same thing

Comment: Why would someone downvote this an not leave a comment explaining why that is just so unhelpful

Comment: Do you use any DI like Autofac? If yes, I guess you have missed registering the controller

Comment: @KaranDesai I am not using any DI

Comment: Why do you initialize services in the constructor instead of initializing them in the method signature and then assigning them like this.spClient = spClient and so on. You would have to put InMemoryCache cacheService in the method signature then.